# Pinging external .dev tld resolve to localhost, but not with Dig

Tags: linux, dns, dig

I installed `puma-dev` last year, forgot about it after I changed jobs. The gist is: it overwrote the `dev` tld to resolve locally during the entire google `.dev` tld ownership thing.

The problem I'm having is that npm is trying to resolve `bit.dev`, and can't, because it's looking now at the localhost.

```
PING bit.dev(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
^C
--- bit.dev ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.036/0.036/0.037/0.000 ms
```

But, `dig` on the other hand correctly finds it.

```
/etc/resolvconf# dig bit.dev

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> bit.dev
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30323
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bit.dev.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bit.dev.        300 IN  A   104.18.26.210
bit.dev.        300 IN  A   104.18.27.210

;; Query time: 56 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 18 18:18:21 EDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68
```

The very amusing part of it all is that while Chrome can't seem to resolve any `.dev` tld's, Firefox can. That'd normally not be an issue, except

Unfortunately all of the answer on **SU** all seem to reference OSX, where the dns facilities are pretty different. I'm currently just at a loss as to the inconsistent behavior between chrome/firefox & ping/dig and what I'd have to touch to begin to figure out *where* this even begins.

Comment: Dig will always use the DNS server, ping however can use a multitude of services to resolve a name like hosts, nis, ...Under linux this is described in /etc/nsswitch.conf, but i have no idea what OSX uses. As to why FF/Chrome have different behaviour, who knows. Maybe one has dns over https enabled and the other not, maybe like ping they chose their name resolution options differently ? There's not enough information on your setup to answer that.

Comment: Try `sudo puma-dev -cleanup`. If you wish to uninstall Puma totally with all unneeded dependencies, use `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove puma `.

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately -cleanup is a mac only one. i've removed all of the downloaded code, everything from Go, but it made some sort of system change that I haven't been able to deduce.

Comment: @Silbee yeah, I don't have enough information to begin to like, get past this block of not knowing enough to search for what I don't currently know. I'm just trying to hail mary before i tear down the entire OS just because I can't find what actually changed in the OS.

Comment: Did you delete Puma by `apt-get purge`?

Comment: The only thing i see is that under linux puma.dev used to be installed with tld-resolver. Maybe that still lingers on your system ? What does your nsswitch.conf look like ? Does /etc/environment have a line like DEV_TLD_DOMAINS=dev ? You can safely remove that.

Comment: Pointing me back to the nsswitch.conf showed me there was something else there that may have caused this and needed removal. Thanks @Silbee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems puma-dev has messed with your DNS config.

Would the following issue help you figure out the problem:
https://github.com/puma/puma-dev/issues/204

Also you might want to look at https://github.com/puma/dev-tld-resolver

Check the following files:

`/etc/hosts`  you don't want any .dev entries
`/etc/nsswitch.conf`  Remove `dev_tld` from the line `hosts:` 
`/etc/environment` Check you don't have a `DEV_TLD_DOMAINS` defined

Puma could also have created filese under `/etc/resolver/`
Like `/etc/resolver/dev`

Comment: Yeah I've already looked @ that issue 204, and have cleared out all those places. I'm assuming there is something else that I wasn't able to grok from the makefiles that changed some value during the installation process.

Comment: Between you and @Silbee here, there wasn't a `dev_tld` entry, but something else that was causing the block that did _roughly_ the same thing (Prax), that I just needed to uninstall then. Didn't fix the chrome issue, but it did allow me to hit the terminal to ping correctly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your ping is defaulting to IPv6.  Try forcing ping to use IPv4 using the command:

```
ping bit.dev -4
```

It could be that bit.dev does not support IPv6.

Comment: Sadly, ping is still hitting local host!